# Randomly permuting large lists (over 100 million elements)

Tags: haskell

I do not care to do it in a "functional" way. But I do need it to be in linear time (not O(n log n)), and I really prefer the type signature to stay intact (ie, not adding additional type constraints). This is what I have so far, but I keep getting a stack overflow:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.STRef
import System.Random

randomPermute :: RandomGen g => [a] -> g -> ([a],g)
randomPermute l rgen = runST $ newListArray (1,n) l >>= body rgen where
  n = length l
  body :: RandomGen g => g -> STArray s Int e -> ST s ([e],g)
  body rgen arr = do
    rgenRef <- newSTRef rgen
    let pick i j   = do vi <- readArray arr i
                        vj <- readArray arr j
                        writeArray arr j vi
                        return vj
        rand lo hi = do rgen <- readSTRef rgenRef
                        let (v,rgen') = randomR (lo,hi) rgen
                        writeSTRef rgenRef rgen'
                        return v
    rv <- forM [1..n] $ \i -> do
        j <- rand i n
        pick i j
    rgen <- readSTRef rgenRef
    return (rv,rgen)

ascCount x = sum $ map oneIfBig $ zip x $ tail x where
  oneIfBig (x,y) = if x<y then 0 else 1

main = do
  -- Using String types just for testing
  res <- getStdRandom $ randomPermute $ map show [1..1000000]
  putStrLn $ show $ ascCount res
```

Now my dealings with imperative languages tell me that there should be a way to avoid using the stack all together. But in Haskell, I can't seem to figure out how. I found some approaches that work if I use unboxed arrays. But like I said, I would prefer not to add additional constraints. Any ideas?

EDIT: I would also appreciate it if somebody can explain to me how the code above is consuming stack space, and why I cannot simply avoid that using tail recursive calls. I tried using eager evaluation in some places, but it didn't help

Answer (score 5):

Random list permutation can be done in /O(n)/ (assuming you have a random input array), via the vector package, using the [`backpermute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:17) operation.

```
backpermute :: Unbox a => Vector a -> Vector Int -> Vector a

/O(n)/
Yield the vector obtained by replacing each element i of the index vector by xs!i. This is equivalent to map (xs!) is but is often much more efficient.
```

I.e.

```
 backpermute <a,b,c,d> <0,3,2,3,1,0> = <a,d,c,d,b,a>
```

You can create efficient random vectors via [a number of packages.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial#Random_numbers)

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't this simply change the problem into one of generating integer permutations? If I understood it right, your packages (mersenne-random, vector-random etc.) do not export any method for producing vectors with non-duplicate elements.

Since I am relatively new to haskell, I would also like to know how the GHC runtime is using up stack space in the code I pasted, so that I do not make the same mistakes again

Comment: It breaks the problem into an O(n) component to perform the permutation, and an O(n log n) step to generate unique randoms (via membership of a Set)

Comment: Ah, so we are back to O(n log n). Ok, thanks. Can we avoid that, though? Just curious

Answer (score 0):

I think just found a linear time solution myself, so I thought I should add it here. Apparently it's simply a bad idea to generate lists from monadic functions like forM or replicateM. They use up stack space. Instead I used the loops just for purely imperative-like processing, and then convert arrays to lists outside the loops. The code is pasted below.

In case anybody is interested, there is a great usenix post [here](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/perfect-shuffle.txt) that does the same thing in a purely functional way, but uses O(n log n) time.

```
randomPermute :: RandomGen g => [a] -> g -> ([a],g)
randomPermute x rgen = (body,rgen2) where
  (rgen1,rgen2) = split rgen
  body = elems $ runST $ do
    g   <- newSTRef rgen1
    arr <- newArray x
    let newInd st = do
          (i,rgen') <- liftM (randomR (st,n-1)) (readSTRef g)
          writeSTRef g rgen'
          return i
    forM_ [0..n-1] $ \i -> do
      j <- newInd i
      p <- readArray arr i
      q <- readArray arr j
      writeArray arr j p
      writeArray arr i q
    unsafeFreeze arr
  n = length x
  newArray :: [a] -> ST s (STArray s Int a)
  newArray x = newListArray (0,length x-1) x
```